# css - what could be causing this?

Tags: css

I have a an outside div (in blue) and an inside div. I am not sure what it is having an effect on the adjacent div. Any ideas? Removing the content of the inside div causes it go back to normal.

EDIT #1

Here's a new image and the css. It seems like the pairings-box is causing some vertical offset to take place.

[image]

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.wide-box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 450px;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.pairings-box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

<div class='wide-box clearfix'></div>

<div class='wide-box clearfix'></div>

<div class='wide-box clearfix'>
  <div class='pairings-box'>here is some text</div>
</div>

<div class='wide-box clearfix'></div>
```

Comment: The image is helpful, but can we see your actual HTML and CSS please?

Comment: Have you tried `display: inline-block`? I have a similar issue with one of my sites at the moment and this fixed some problems but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the blue `<div>`s have a `display: block;` as you suggest. The displayed behaviour is normal for `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: let me try to simplify the code and post. thx

Comment: I had the same problem on some of my divs, inline-block helped for some but with others it didn't. The float as suggested by @jacktheripper just solved my problem, I just did a test and changed inline-block to block, it made no difference in my case.

Comment: I'm sorry - I think you're right Neil

Comment: my clearfix was forcing display:inline-block to be display:block and I think this was causing it. Will update if not

Comment: Neil is correct, and when setting boxes like these to inline-block, set the vertical-align to top on those inline-blocks to prevent this issue in the future.

Comment: thx Neil and stom... for help on this. def not my forte

Answer (score 1):

Try float the content inside it left.

Example before floats [here](http://jsfiddle.net/77dpW/4/)

Example after floats [here](http://jsfiddle.net/77dpW/)

Comment: Beauty, that fixed my remaining problem... I hope it helps @timpone - thanks mate... hehe

Comment: let me take a look at this - I think this might be it. Will make some adjustments and test. thx jtr

Comment: not initially but let me spend some time with this. It looks like it should. I want to put a bunch more css in these boxes and have had problems with floating a bunch of independent elements.